# Reusing FormBuilder

Tags: c#, botframework

My bot receives some user info like order no and few other details based on that it searches the orders. If more that 1 order is returned then it asks user to provide more info so asks for 2 additional details.

Now my problem is that as I have already build the form using FormBuilder and on completion I ask user to provide more info so that should be the approach to ask for additional info. Should I create another form and request info or is there any way to add the additional fields to the same form in the completion method.

I want to ask for more user inputs after initial search is complete and msg for more than 1 order found is displayed.

As my properties SubOrderNumber & SubOrderVersion are in OrderQuery class so Should i build new form for OrderQuery or is there anyother way to add these two to existing Order form.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;

namespace Bot
{
    [Serializable]
    public class OrderSearchQuery
    {
        [Prompt("Please enter {&}")]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Please enter {&}?")]
        public String Location { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Please provide last status {&}?")]
        public string Status{ get; set; }

        [Prompt("Please enter {&}?")]
        public string SubOrderNumber { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Please enter {&}?")]
        public string SubOrderVersion { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace Bot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class OrderDialog : IDialog<object>
    {

        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Welcome to the Order helper!");

            var orderFormDialog = FormDialog.FromForm(this.BuildOrderForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);

            context.Call(orderFormDialog, this.ResumeAfterOrdersFormDialog);
        }

        private IForm<OrderSearchQuery> BuildOrderForm()
        {
            OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<OrderSearchQuery> processOrderSearch = async (context, state) =>
            {
                await context.PostAsync($"Ok. Searching for Orders with Number: {state.OrderNumber}...");
            };

            return new FormBuilder<OrderSearchQuery>()
                .Field(nameof(OrderSearchQuery.OrderNumber))
                .AddRemainingFields(new string[] { nameof(RequiredDWPSearchQuery.SubOrderNumber), nameof(RequiredDWPSearchQuery.SubOrderVersion) })
                .OnCompletion(processOrderSearch)
                .Build();
        }

        private async Task ResumeAfterOrdersFormDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<OrderSearchQuery> result)
        {
            try
            {
                var searchQuery = await result;

                await context.PostAsync($"I found total of 100 Ordes");

                await context.PostAsync($"To get Order details, you will need to provide more info...");

}
            catch (FormCanceledException ex)
            {
                string reply;

                if (ex.InnerException == null)
                {
                    reply = "You have canceled the operation. Quitting from the Required DWP Search";
                }
                else
                {
                    reply = $"Oops! Something went wrong :( Technical Details: {ex.InnerException.Message}";
                }

                await context.PostAsync(reply);
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Done<object>(null);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are conditional parameters for fields and the possibility of doing logic in validation, I don't believe that would be the cleanest way to go. I would take a two dialog approach.

Here's the original form, with additional parameters removed:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
using System;

namespace TestChatbot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class OrderSearchQuery
    {
        [Prompt("Please enter {&}")]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Please enter {&}?")]
        public String Location { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Please provide last status {&}?")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Instead, I moved the additional properties to a new form:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
using System;

namespace TestChatbot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class OrderFollowUp
    {
        [Prompt("Please enter {&}?")]
        public string SubOrderNumber { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Please enter {&}?")]
        public string SubOrderVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I added logic to handle the second form, depending on the results of the search:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;

namespace TestChatbot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Welcome to the Order helper!");

            var orderFormDialog = FormDialog.FromForm(this.BuildOrderForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);

            context.Call(orderFormDialog, this.ResumeAfterOrdersFormDialog);
        }

        private IForm<OrderSearchQuery> BuildOrderForm()
        {
            return new FormBuilder<OrderSearchQuery>()
                .Build();
        }

        private IForm<OrderFollowUp> BuildFollowUpForm()
        {
            return new FormBuilder<OrderFollowUp>()
                .Build();
        }

        private async Task ResumeAfterOrdersFormDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<OrderSearchQuery> result)
        {
            try
            {
                var searchQuery = await result;
                await context.PostAsync($"Ok. Searching for Orders with Number: {searchQuery.OrderNumber}...");
                await context.PostAsync($"I found total of 100 Ordes");

                int searchResultCount = 2;

                if (searchResultCount > 1)
                {
                    await context.PostAsync($"To get Order details, you will need to provide more info...");
                    var followUpDialog = FormDialog.FromForm(this.BuildFollowUpForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);

                    context.Call(followUpDialog, this.ResumeAfterFollowUpDialog);
                }
            }
            catch (FormCanceledException ex)
            {
                string reply;

                if (ex.InnerException == null)
                {
                    reply = "You have canceled the operation. Quitting from the Required DWP Search";
                }
                else
                {
                    reply = $"Oops! Something went wrong :( Technical Details: {ex.InnerException.Message}";
                }

                await context.PostAsync(reply);
            }
        }

        private async Task ResumeAfterFollowUpDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<OrderFollowUp> result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Order complete.");
            context.Done<object>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

The difference here is that I removed the OnCompletion call and handled that logic on the resumption handler, after the first dialog completes. Based on the search result, you can call the second dialog, much like you did the first to extract additional information.

Comment: Great answer. Yesterday I almost did the same but urs seems to be a lot cleaner approach.